# How is `size` being initialized & accepted as a parameter, if it's not in any subclass nor superclass property, nor '_' is used before it?

Tags: swift

In the `init()` function (line 68), inside `class TriangleAndSquare`, how come there's a need for the parameter label `size` to be initialized, and how is it being accepted as a parameter even though it's not a property in any subclass (including that class itself) or superclass?

Also how is `size` being accepted as an argument (lines 69 & 70) it seems, for type `Square: NameShape` (line 14) in its `init()` function (line 17), when `class Square: NameShape` doesn't even have `size` as one of it's properties too [nor is `size` in the superclass: `NameShape` (line 1)], nor is it being initialized in 'class Square: NameShape`?

Shouldn't there be an underscore `_` before `size` in `class TriangleAndSquare`'s `init()` function parameter (line 68), perhaps as `init(_ size: Double, name: String)` so that any argument label, when an object is created, can be accepted as its parameter?

This code is from the 'GuidedTour.playground' file from their 'The Swift Programming Language 4.2' (it's in their Swift 5 version, of the same book, as well). The code is in the section: 'Classes and Objects'.

I've already digested the Apple docs and some good video tutorials on the purpose and nature of: initialization, argument, argument labels, parameters & parameter labels but I guess, I need another view/explanation on these.

```
1    class NamedShape {
2        var numberOfSides: Int = 0
3        var name: String
4    
5        init(name: String) {
6            self.name = name
7        }
8    
9        func simpleDescription() -> String {
10          return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
11       } 
12    }
13
14    class Square: NamedShape {
15        var sideLength: Double
16    
17        init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
18            self.sideLength = sideLength
19            super.init(name: name)
20            numberOfSides = 4
21        }
22    
23        func area() -> Double {
24            return sideLength * sideLength
25        }
26    
27        override func simpleDescription() -> String {
28            return "A square with sides of length \(sideLength)."
29        } 
30    }
31
32    class EquilateralTriangle: NamedShape {
33        var sideLength: Double = 0.0
34    
35        init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
36            self.sideLength = sideLength
37            super.init(name: name)
38            numberOfSides = 3
39        }
40    
41        var perimeter: Double {
42            get {
43                return 3.0 * sideLength
44            }
45            set {
46                sideLength = newValue / 3.0
47            }
48        }
49    
50        override func simpleDescription() -> String {
51            return "An equilateral triangle with sides of length \ (sideLength)."
52        } 
53    }
54
55    class TriangleAndSquare {
56        var triangle: EquilateralTriangle {
57            willSet {
58                square.sideLength = newValue.sideLength
59            }
60        }
61
62        var square: Square {
63            willSet {
64                triangle.sideLength = newValue.sideLength
65            }
66        }
67
68        init(size: Double, name: String) {
69            square = Square(sideLength: size, name: name)
70            triangle = EquilateralTriangle(sideLength: size, name: name)
71        } 
72    }
```

I expected it to have an error but this not-so-common initialization, parameter & argument labels acceptance did not produce any error in Apple's Swift book.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with any of the code you are asking about. It all makes perfect sense.

Comment: It may be helpful to read the [Function Parameters and Return Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID160) and [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) sections in the Swift book chapter on Functions.

Comment: Having an argument labeled `size` in the initialiser dose not necessarily mean that there is a property named `size`. It is just a value input for the class to initialise any of its properties. In this case, the size is passed to become the `sideLength` of the underlying `Square` and `EquilateralTriangle`.

Comment: You don't have to pass a variable with the same name as the argument label, only the Type matters. `sideLength` is just a label, it accepts type `Double`. `size` is a variable with type `Double`. Therefore `square = Square(sideLength: size, name: name)` makes total sense.

Comment: @RickyMo Why not post your comments as an answer?

Comment: @RickyMo I see, where what's the use of the underscore score then, if any name for the argument, can be passed to any name in the parameter? Why was an exception, it seems, made for this code?

Comment: *Why was it an exception

Answer (score 0):

Having an argument labeled `size` in the initialiser dose not necessarily mean that there is a property named `size`. It is just a value input for the class to initialise any of its properties. In this case, the `size` is passed to become the `sideLength` of the underlying Square and EquilateralTriangle.

You don't have to pass a variable with the same name as the argument label, only the Type matters. `sideLength` is just a label, it accepts type `Double`. `size` is a variable with type `Double`. Therefore `square = Square(sideLength: size, name: name)` makes total sense.

If you specify both argument label and variable name in a function, it would look like something like `func foo(n x : Int){print(x)}`, where `n` is the argument label, `x` is the variable name when refering it inside the function, `Int` is the type of this argument. This function will be called with `foo(n:1)`

The underscore is used if you want that argument don't have a label.

For example `func foo(_ x : Int){print(x)}` can be called with `foo(1)`. You may ask when would this be useful? That is when your function arguments are so obvious that adding a label does not provide more readability.

e.g. `func sum(_ a : Int, _ b: Int){return a + b}` obviously adding label to either of the input does not improve the readability at all as they have no meaning. `sum(a:1,b:2)` is NOT a readability improvement over `sum(1,2)`.

If you don't provide separated argument label and variable name, the same name will be used as both argument label and variable name.

e.g. `func foo(x : Int){print(x)}` has to be called with `foo(x : 1)`